# I cannot start virtual device in Genymotion?

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

I downloaded  device "Google Nexus S - 4.1.1-API 16-400x800" in my Genymotion player. When I try to start the device, player start to loading android and after about half minute pop up window with the  message "player.exe stopped working".
I managed to start the device from virtual box without any problems.
Why I cannot start the device from Genymotion player?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked "virtual device path" in genymotion go to vbox folder ?

if not try make vdp to C:\Users{comp. name}\AppData\Local/Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/